# Custom UITableView cell with autolayout has wrong width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I created a UITableViewCell with autolayout using xib in which the width of cell is 400.
In iOS7 simulator, It works fine, the width will be adjusted to the width of tableview. But In iOS8, the width is still 400, and then part of the cell is not in the screen.

If I use [cell setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO], the layout constrains in cell's contentview will all disappered.

**So my question is how to make the width of cell same with the tableview, and keep the constrain in the tableviewcell?**

Sorry for my poor English.